# Trouble passing form fields between components at higher level form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting started with Vue, I need to create a form of tiered select fields.  That is the selected option for A, uses that to call the API to get the options for B, which determines options for C.

I'm still pretty new to frontend frameworks so this might be a terrible design.  However not every inclusion of A (`SelectState.vue`) in a view requires all the children so making them modular was my first thought.

Currently I have a top level component that displays the select options:

> SelectState.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="select-state">
    <span>{{ label }}</span>
    <select v-model="selectedState">
      <option v-for="state in states" :key="state">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'select-state',
  data: function () {
    return {
      selectedState: '',
      states: ['TX']
    }
  },
  props: ['label']
  // this.states = axios.get('xxx')
}
</script>
```

> Index.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="form">
    <v-select-state label="State"></v-select-state>
    <v-select-zip label="Zip"></v-select-zip>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SelectState from './SelectState.vue'
import SelectZip from './SelectZip.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {
    'v-select-state': SelectState,
    'v-select-Zip': SelectZip
  }
}
</script>
```

Then I have a `SelectZip.vue` that is identical to `SelectState.vue` except that it has a parameter for its `axios.get('XXX', params = {'state': ???})`.  But I'm stuck on how to "pass" that necessary parameter.

Thanks in advance!

edit: In conjunction with @dziraf's answer my working although verbose `SelectedZip.vue` is as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="select_zip">
    <span>{{ label }}</span>
    <select v-model="selected_zip">
      <option v-for="zip in zips" :key="zip">
        {{ zip }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'select_zip',
  data: function () {
    return {
      zips: []
    }
  },
  props: ['label'],
  computed: {
    selected_zip: {
      get () { return this.$store.state.formModule.zip },
      set (value) { this.$store.commit('formModule/setZips', value) }
    },
    selected_state: {
      get () { return this.$store.state.formModule.state }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getValidZips (state) {
      axios.post('/api/v1/get_valid_zips', {
        params:{'state': state }})
        .then(response => {
          this.zips = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected_state (value) {
      this.getValidZips(value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you want to pass parameter from component to another?

Comment: That's the best way I can articulate that idea, when one component's selected field changes I needed another's to change based on that selected field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it by adding 'state' `props` to your select components from your main form component, but I think it isn't a good long-term solution.

Instead, consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html). An example configuration would look like this:

**@/store/modules/form.js**

```
const Form = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    state: '',
    zip: ''
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
    setState (state, payload) {
      state.state = payload
    },
    setZip (state, payload) {
      state.zip = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {}
}

export default Form
```

**@/store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Form from './modules/form'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    formModule: Form,
  }
})

export default store
```

**@/main.js**

```
// your impots
import store from './store/index'
// your configs
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store, // add store to your main Vue instance so it's accessible with this.$store
  axios,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
});
```

This would be your **SelectState.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="select-state">
    <span>{{ label }}</span>
    <select v-model="selectedState">
      <option v-for="state in states" :key="state">
        {{ state }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  name: 'select-state',
  data: function () {
    return {
      states: ['TX']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    selectedState: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.formModule.state },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('formModule/setState', value) }
    }
  },
  props: ['label']
}
</script>
```

Your **SelectZip.vue** would be the same, except you would instead use your store's `zip` as your v-model.

Your store variables are accessible across your app and you can access them with `computed` properties in your components.

Comment: In order for `SelectZip.vue` to get the currently set state, should I use `this.$store.getter.getZip()` or is it okay to just access the `this.$store.state.zip` directly?

Comment: Access it as a `computed` property like `selectedState` in **SelectState.vue** example. Getters are actually not getters you would see in OOP, but rather something like `computed` properties in your regular components. For example, let's say you have a `tasks` state (array of objects). If you ever needed tasks that are done, you would create a getter `completedTasks` like so: `completedTasks: state => { return state.tasks.filter(task => task.done) }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!  However I misstyped my last comment, I meant to ask how should I get the currently selectedState from inside `SelectZip.vue`, by using components still?  Example: Inside `SelectZip.vue` i'm trying to watch for changes to the selected state and then call `axios.get("XXX", {"state": this.$store.state.formModule.state})`

Comment: If you have a `set(value)` in your `computed` property, it should automatically update store's state on select?

Comment: And just a note; don't access your store's state directly like you did in your `axios.get` example. Map it to a computed property instead so it remains reactive.

Comment: Yes store's state is changing, but I need my zip select field to get the new possibilities based on whatever the new state a user selected.  I actually just got it to work with adding a `computed: selected_state` and a `watch: selected_state` inside my `SelectZip.vue` but the documentation seems like I shouldn't be using watch for this easy example

Comment: I see. I would move `getValidZips` to the store as an `action` and dispatch it when you select `state`:
`set(value) { this.$store.commit('formModule/setState', value); this.$store.dispatch('formModule/getValidZips') }`. You can also try making `zips` a `computed` property and return axios result. When `state` changes it should make a request, but you need to check that.